# Qt query.value return wrong chars (char encoding)

Tags: database, qt, character-encoding

I have a database field with string like "PRODUCT N°1" when do:

```
QString name = query.value(PRODUCT_INDEX_NAME).toString()
```

I get: "PRODUCT N?1". Degree symbol was lost.

I think is a char encoding problem. How can fix ?

More info:

- Database is Visual FoxPro (I don't know it's char encoding, maybe Windows-1252)
- Query is performed via QODBC
- When open database with dbfViewer in dos view string is show as "PRODUCT N¦1" and in windows view correctly as "PRODUCT N°1".

Output of:
`query.value(PRODUCT_INDEX_NAME).toByteArray()` is:

```
    "PRODUCT N?1  " QByteArray
    [0] 80 'P'  char
    [1] 82 'R'  char
    [2] 79 'O'  char
    [3] 68 'D'  char
    [4] 85 'U'  char
    [5] 67 'C'  char
    [6] 84 'T'  char
    [7] 32 ' '  char
    [8] 78 'N'  char
    [9] 63 '?'  char
    [10]49 '1'  char
```

As seen above internally char '°' is already converted to byte 63 ('?') so trying as suggested below by 'webclectic' don't works anyway.

Comment: Please post here the hex string that results from `query.value(PRODUCT_INDEX_NAME).toByteArray().toHex();`

Comment: Hex string: 50524f44554354204e3f31

Comment: Ok, I see the 0x3f is indeed the '?' question mark character.

Comment: I think this might be due to a problem with the [QODBC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qodbc) driver. Take a look at the notes on Unicode support.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the value in `QByteArray` and then use the correct `QTextCodec` in order to transform it to a `QString`. For example if the codec was Windows-1250 you could do:

```
QTextCodec* windows1250Codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1250");
QString name  = 
   windows1250Codec->toUnicode(query.value(PRODUCT_INDEX_NAME).toByteArray());
```

Check the `QTextCodec` [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html) for more info and for a list of available codecs.

Answer (score 1):

QString support Unicode, and ° (0xB0) is an invalid UTF-8 encoded byte for a character code start.

Try to change the database encoding to UTF-8 when you create the database :

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

If it still doesn't work, try with utf16 also.

But if you cannot modify DB, you have to setup connection options within your Qt application source code :

```
// db is the instance of QSqlDatabase
db.setConnectOptions("ISC_DPB_LC_CTYPE=Latin1");
```

But this option may not be supported by the Qt Visual Fox Pro driver because ISC_DPB_LC_CTYPE is for InterBase as shown in the page at http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/sql-driver.html (see § QIBASE Unicode Support and Text Encoding).
I don't have any Visual Foxpro documentation to find the connection option name for the character encoding.

Comment: I just edited my answer, but I can't help more because I don't have Visual foxpro documentation.