# Qt SQL Server and the umlauts

Tags: sql, sql-server, qt, odbc, qsqlquery

- OS: Windows 8.1
- MS SQL Server 2008 R2
- Qt 5.2
- DB Driver "QODBC"

I have a little problem with the umlaut.

I create the table with a column NVARCHAR(35) and fill the table with N’1ö2’. When I select something from the SQL Management Studio I see the umlaut ö.

In Qt I use e.g. this `qDebug() << “name“ << aQuery->value(„name“).toString();` but I get `name "1?2"`

Even when I loop the available codecs (QTextCodec::availableCodecs();) I don’t get a valid 1ö2 string.

```
QByteArray ba = aQuery->value(„name").toByteArray();
qDebug() << "hex" << ba.toHex() << "str" << QString(ba) << "count" << ba.count();
```

Output:

```
hex "31efbfbd32" str "1?2" count 5
```

31 is 1
32 is 2
efbfbd is unicode for ? (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)

So my question is pretty simple - what I’m doing wrong? ;-)

Thanks, Matthias

Comment: A similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717328/qt-query-value-return-wrong-chars-char-encoding

Comment: Are you using the MDAC ODBC driver (SQLSRV32.dll) or the native client (SQLNCLI11.dll) ODBC driver?

Comment: MS SQL uses afaik UTF8 by default (or better ucs-2) and I already tried to change the ConnectionOptions ([link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions)), no success.


I tried SQL Server (SQLSRV32.dll), SQL Server Native Client 10.0 (SQLNCLI10.dll) as well as ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server (MSODBCSQL11.dll) - same behavior.


I tried to the change the connection string (added „AutoTranslate=No;Regional=No“) and created a System-DSN in the ODBC manager (converting checkbox off) - same behavior.

Comment: Okay it works now. 
A single aQuery.clear; before I do the request did it. ;-)

Comment: Great news, you should write that as an answer and accept that answer, so it is easier to find for future vistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it works now. A single 
`aQuery.clear;`
before I do the request did it. ;-)